# C++ socket send/recv vs write/read

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

In socket `ssize_t send(int __fd, const void* __buf, size_t __n, int __flags)` we got this `__flags` argument. I'm using `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag all through the connection. Is there a way to achieve this flag functionality in `write`? Since I'm using this flag all through the connection, It could be set when `socket` is created. Feel free to mention If there are ways to achieve all the `__flag` functions.

Answer (score 44):

No. When writing to a socket with `write` it's the same thing as calling `send` with the `flags` argument set to zero.

From the [official POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)

> If *fildes* refers to a socket, *write()* shall be equivalent to [*send()*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) with no flags set.

---

There is however a way of "setting" this flag permanently, and that is to ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: this would ignore the signal for all connections by the procees, anyway can u help me with remaining flags? I gave an upvote but can't accept the answer. Thanq!

Comment: @neckTwi The other two official flags (as well as those supported by [`recv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html#) are specific to the message being sent (or received), and not something that can be set on a per-connection or per-socket (or per-process or per-thread) basis.